# Why am I getting no output from this short Perl script?

Tags: perl, return-value

Why isn't the below code returning any output? I am expecting it to print out "Contains".

```
sub is_member {
    my ($x, @list) = @_;
    foreach (@list) { 
        if ($x eq $_) {"contains"} else {"doesn't contain"}
        }
    }

my @a = qw(apple x orange but so nos how dod to it a b c);
print is_member("apple",@a)."\n";
```

Like below code just run fine, outputting "is palindrome"

```
sub is_palindrome {
    my ($x) = @_;
    if ($x eq reverse($x)){"is palindrome"} else {"Not a palindrome"} 
    }
print is_palindrome("radar")."\n";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
if ($x eq $_) {"contains"} else {"doesn't contain"}
```

does not print or return anything.  It evaluates two constants, but that's all.  I'm surprised there isn't a complaint about missing semicolons, too.  And the indentation is eccentric.

You probably want something more like:

```
sub is_member
{
    my ($x, @list) = @_;
    foreach (@list)
    { 
        return "contains" if ($x eq $_);
    }
    return "doesn't contain";
}
```

Comment: I think the syntax is correct, it by defaults returns the value. The below code just works fine and prints "is palindrome" `sub is_palindrome {
    my ($x) = @_;
    if ($x eq reverse($x)){"is palindrome"} else {"Not a palindrome"} 
    }
print is_palindrome("radar")."\n";`

Comment: If you like to live dangerously, don't complain when things go wrong.  And don't submit code like that to me for code review — I will reject it every time.  In the context of your code, if you got anything returned, it would be "doesn't contain" because the last iteration of the loop evaluates to false when the key you're looking for is "apple".  You need to terminate the loop early, or do an explicit return.  Using implicit return is tacky Perl and unreliable to boot.

Comment: thx, using ( return "contains";) works fine, since this was going all over the loop last item doesn't match and it didn't print anything.

Comment: There's no complaint about missing semicolons because Perl uses them as statement _separators_, not statement _terminators_. Since there's no following statement in the block to separate the values from, semicolons are not required. (But should probably still be included anyhow, to avoid problems when a future maintainer inevitably adds to the block contents.)

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops do not have return values. In `is_palindrome`, the `if` statement is evaluated by itself which produces the return value for the subroutine implicitly.

In the case of the `for` loop, even if the last statement evaluated inside a for loop became the return value, the last comparison made, `"apple" eq "c"`, would be false.

If you want to do the test using a `for` loop, you will need to [exit the loop early](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314204/100754). But, in Perl, `grep` is the built-in way to test if the elements of a list satisfy a condition.

```
my $result = (grep $_ eq $x, @list) ? "contains" : "does not contain";
print "'@list' $result $x\n";
```

If you are only interested in the existence of a certain element, [List::MoreUtils::any](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#any-BLOCK-LIST)
and [List::MoreUtils::first_index](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#first_index-BLOCK-LIST) provide performance advantages in case the list is long.

The [conditional operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Conditional-Operator), `$cond ? $t : $f`, is more useful for writing compact conditionals than trying to fit an `if` statement on a single line with braces and all.

Answer (score 0):

to clarify on the return values of subs, by default, Perl returns the value of the evaluation of the last expression in the sub... unless it's in a loop. from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> If no return is found and if the last statement is an expression, its
>   value is returned. If the last statement is a loop control structure
>   like a foreach or a while , the returned value is unspecified. The
>   empty sub returns the empty list.

but as others have stated, you should always use `return` if you are returning anything, for both readability and stability.

it's also true that your sub is unnecessary. `grep` will return 0 or 1 in a scalar context (that you can use as boolean), or a new array of matching values in an array context; ex:

```
my @a = qw(apple x orange but so nos how dod to it a b c);
print "found" if grep /^orange$/, @a; # prints "found"
my @b = grep length > 3, @a; 
print "@b" # prints "apple orange"
```